# System Verilog Conditional Type Definition

Tags: typedef, system-verilog

Is there a way to conditionally select between two types based on a parameter value?

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic a;
} my_type_1_t;

typedef struct packed {
  logic [1:0] a;
} my_type_2_t;

parameter type type_t = my_type_1_t;

if (MY_PARAM == 1) begin
  typedef my_type_1_t type_t;
  do something...
end else begin
  typedef my_type_2_t type_t;
  do the same something as above with different struct...
end

type_t my_signal;
```

As you can see, I need to do the same operations in the `else` clause as in the `if` clause, but on a different struct. This seems redundant to me, and I am curious if there is a way to avoid duplication.

Comment: Why not make the entire part of the module that uses the type be inside the generate block? As Dave said, outside the generate block wouldn't know how to use that type anyway. Perhaps you can suffice to just put part of the module inside the generate, then convert to some other value that is common to all code outside the block.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but that required duplicating a lot of logic for both `if...else` cases just because they have different structures. I updated my example in the question above to have the same signal, but with different widths. It looks redundant to me that I have to have to same logic just for differing signal widths. Since there is a way to do it through `parameter type`, I thought there should be a way through raw integer parameters.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this because the type_t name will be local to the generate-if block. But it wouldn't make much sense if you could because code that references my_signal is going to want to access my_signal.b and it would not exist in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! The idea is, based on a parameter passed from above, the module should pick one of the two structs and operate on it. One way I know is to pass a `parameter type` from above, but that creates issues with other tools, so I want to avoid doing that. So I would rather pass a plain integer parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to mimic the behavior you want is to use parameterized modules.

Here is a simple example:

```
typedef struct {
  logic a, b;
} type1_t;

typedef struct {
  logic [1:0] a1, b1;
} type2_t;

module top(input logic clk);

  pmod#(.T(type1_t)) inst1(clk);
  pmod#(.T(type2_t)) inst2(clk);

endmodule

module pmod#(type T=int) (input logic clk);
  logic [1:0] a, b;
  T t;

  if ($typename(T) == "type1_t") begin
     always @(posedge clk) begin
      a = t.a;
      b = t.b;
    end
  end
  else if ($typename(T) == "type2_t") begin
    always @(posedge clk) begin
      a = t.a1;
      b = t.b1;
    end
  end

  // do something with a and b

endmodule
```

Comment: Got it! There're issues using parameter type in backend, so I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.  I thought the OP's post was about removing redundancy, by not having an if...else.   Also, I read the question as that the two structs have the same interface and will be doing exact same operations in the two cases

Comment: nevermind, I think you may have answered the original question, before it was edited.

Answer (score -1):

First, question to ask yourself is whether you are needing synthesizable code?

If not, you simply can use a parameterized `class` with different struct definitions, effectively giving you parameterized structs.

Note that it would be possible for synthesis tools to synthesize such code, yet your mileage with each tool varies, and last time I checked, most synthesis tools didn't even support this limited use of class construct as a scoping mechanism.

Packages, which have much more synthesis tool support unfortunately do not have an option for parameterizing packages/structs.  The best I've done is to emulate parameterizable structs using macros, e.g.:

```
// Macro and struct definitions could be moved to common header file if shared across multiple modules
// Acts like a parameterized typedef
// Note: You could even extend multiple nested levels if needed
// This mechanism requires that the struct definitions take the same form, i.e., logic[0:0] instead of just logic
`define my_type_t(W) struct packed { logic [W-1:0] a; }

// module used as example, but would work in most contexts
module mod;
   parameter MY_PARAM = 1;

   // In a particular parameterized context, can resolve the macro
   //  into a real typedef if desired   
   typedef my_type_t(MY_PARAM) type_t;

   type_t my_signal;
    
   // do something that works with either struct definition
endmodule;
```

Please check my syntax above as I took a previously working example and modified it to match the question from OP, without testing final code segment.

Comment: have you tested it? you need to use back tick in  `typedef ``my_type_t(MY_PARAM) type_t ` in order to get the type name as `my_type_MY_PARAM_t`

Comment: The code segment was just an example to illustrate.  It says right in the post that the syntax has not been fully checked.  The goal wasn't to provide a push-button solution, which is why there are also comments about where details should be filled in according to specific needds.  Did you find that once fixing any minor syntax issues, the solution didn't solve the original question as asked?

Comment: this is not a solution, because it just does not work and cannot work. The language does not allow substitution of elaboration time constant values into a pre-processing constructs. So, it will end up with the name of type `my_type_MY_PARAM_t` and never with something like *my_type_1_t*, which was expected.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback.  It helps to understand why was downvoted, so that the answer can be fixed.  The text concatenation macro wasn't really essential to the concept that was being conveyed, and so has been removed.  From last comment by OP, I believe that the naming of structs may be flexible, as it is more about enabling the reuse of code that is the main issue.